# How to detect the url of a website sending a CURL post

Tags: php, curl

I'm playing around with building a very very simple API where an external website makes a CURL post to my website, and the request is only processed if it comes from a whitelisted URL. It doesn't look like any $_SERVER data captures what website has submitted the post. I know I could build the user CURL code to looks something like:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"url=".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);`

But then nothing would stop the user from just going in and changing it to

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"url=white-listed-url.com");`

I'm not married to CURL, just seemed like the best option. Open to anyway that I can have an external request to my website, and I can get the URL of the site making the request.

Comment: Either make the IP Whitelisted, or do a DNS Request to the given url and check if ip fits to request

Comment: You should probably look at auth with curl, you can easily get past a simple IP whitelist like this

Comment: This is something asked again and again, but it is not possible. The reason is: the client _always_ is able to modify _any_ aspect of the request. You can _never_ trust any data you receive from a client.